# How to mock an element in beforeeach using karma

Tags: angular, typescript, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

My component's ngOnInit calls a queryselector method and on testing the component I see this error:

```
TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'querySelector')
```

Adding just a small code for help:

**parentComponent.component.html:**

```
<app-child id="child"></app-child>
```

**childComponent.component.html:**

```
<div id="xyz"></div>
```

**childComponent.component.ts:**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-child',
  templateUrl: './childComponent.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./childComponent.component.css'],
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

ngOninit() {
 const someElement1 = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById(`child`);
 const someElement2 = someElement1.querySelector('#xyz');
 }
}
```

**childComponent.component.spec.ts:**

```
import { ComponentFixture, TestBed, waitForAsync } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ParentComponent } from '../parent/parentComponent.component';
import { ChildComponent } from './childComponent.component';

describe('src/app/childComponent.component.ts', () => {
  let component: ChildComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ChildComponent>;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ChildComponent, ParentComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
   }));

   beforeEach(() => {
    fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ChildComponent);
    component = fixture.componentInstance;
    fixture.detectChanges();
   });

   it('should create', () => {
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh in the tests. The problem is your fixture setup isn't creating the parent component and because of which the child component and it's inner children are not added in the `document`.

While running the tests only for the `ChildComponent`, they will not be available in the DOM just by creating the instance of child alone. At least by the example posted above, they will not be.

We can write a test like this(for the sake of illustration)...

```
describe('src/app/childComponent.component.ts', () => {
  let component: ChildComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<ChildComponent>;

  beforeEach(waitForAsync(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
        declarations: [ChildComponent, ParentComponent]
    }).compileComponents();
   }));

   beforeEach(() => {
     const parentComponent = TestBed.createComponent(ParentComponent);
     const childDebugElement = parentComponent.debugElement.query(By.directive(ChildComponent));
     component = childDebugElement.componentInstance;
   });

   it('should create', () => {
     expect(component).toBeTruthy();
   });
})
```

Read further in the [angular documentation](https://angular.io/guide/testing-components-scenarios#component-inside-a-test-host) for testing such scenario(s) and such implementation(s).

---

### Typo Correction

This is the code in the `ngOnInit` of `ChildComponent`...

```
ngOninit() {
 const someElement1 = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById(`app-child`);
 const someElement2 = someElement1.querySelector('#xyz');
 }
```

in which we are doing following for `someElement1`..

```
const someElement1 = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById(`app-child`);
```

which will look for an element in the `document` with `id` `app-child`.

However, in the template of the `parent`, we have this...

```
<app-child id="child"></app-child>
```

... an element with id `child`. That means, `<HTMLElement>document.getElementById('app-child');` is going to return a `null` as there exists no element with id `app-child` and so `someElement1` will be `null`, and so in the next line when we are doing `const someElement2 = someElement1.querySelector('#xyz');`, it is expected to throw an error, and which it is.

Comment: Sorry, i made a mistake:
const someElement1 = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById(`app-child`);

should be:

const someElement1 = <HTMLElement>document.getElementById(`child`);
Edited in question

Comment: Are you still getting the same error? You shouldn't.

Comment: Yes, I am still getting it

Comment: @ShaileshPrajapati I also have edited the answer. Please check.